# Control volume with right mouse button + mouse wheel

Tags: mouse

Are there any programs that let me assign custom action such as changing the volume on mouse gestures (right click+scroll wheel), similar to [Volumouse](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html) on Windows?

Comment: There's a good chance Karabiner Elements can do it. It had a fresh start some years back due to El Capitan changing things, but my understanding is that it has a pretty healthy amount of functionality back now. It's free, but not as easy to use as some other applications. in it you define key changes with a JSON file: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html - The new documentation is still a little tight lipped as far as I can tell, but oyu can use the Event Viewer app that comes with it to see which key or device is which and write your JSON file based on that information.

Answer (score 2):

Using **[SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/)** (thanks @CrashBurner), click "**Chords**", then the "**+**" on the bottom left, add shortcut and assign action (under the **Music Control** category).

Note in the image below: Roll Down = Volume Up is because the "natural scrolling" nonsense (for standard mouse wheels) was fixed using "Standard wheel direction" in [SmoothScroll](https://www.smoothscroll.net/mac/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of a new tool for some time, but [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) might be worth a look, but it depends on your current OS version. I'd verify it would work with you machine before you download/purchase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been using SteerMouse for a while, but it does not appear it offers this kind of functionality.

Comment: @friederbluemle, of you're willing to use another shortcut, like `modifier key` + `scrollwheel`, you'd likely have more options. Or if that isn't good enough, Better Touch Tool would give you even more options, at it can handle mice, trackpad gestures, touchbar and keyboard.

Comment: @Joonas - Thanks for your comment! BTT does appear to be very flexible and customizable. I'll play around for a bit. My first attempt (mouse wheel over menu bar) does not seem to trigger any actions... Do you happen to know why?

Comment: I think it's a bug in BTT - If I assign the middle mouse button it works as expected. Once I switch it to "Scroll Up" (or "Scroll Down") nothing is recognized anymore :(

Comment: @friederbluemle, The only thing that came to mind was... if it's a magic mouse, it needs an additional modifier for the scroll up/down trigger. Though if you change that to `swipe up/down` you can pretty much get the same thing except the swipe trigger needs a broader stroke(though the swipe sensitivity can be adjusted in the settings). With a "normal mouse" you don't need the modifier. I just tested both and it worked as intended...

Comment: It's a "normal" mouse. It does detect the scroll wheel in the "Click to record a mouse button:" field of BTT, but then it does not execute any actions when I use the wheel (with or without modifiers). I guess I have to wait for a BTT update. Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: @friederbluemle, I'd perhaps start looking at other applications that might be interfering... Like steermouse, perhaps? My scroll worked just fine, so I'm strongly suspecting something in your setup is breaking it. You can use safe boot to eliminate 3rd party app interference(for testing purposes)... Or as a last resort, make a post in the BTT community forum.

Comment: Nice! It turned out it was SmoothScroll that was interfering. No issues with SteerMouse. After disabling SmoothScroll the mouse wheel clicks were registered (although way too slow, with a 500ms or so delay between "clicks", i.e. BTT action execution). Not sure where the problem is there.. Since scrolling is pretty bad without SmoothScroll, I'll use other options for now, maybe the situation will improve in the future.